# Sequelize findOrCreate loop not finding newly created rows?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I will dumb this down for simplicity. I need to findOrCreate rows based off of a string value (cannot be primary key / id). It must be done in a loop, so it's gotta be async. It is also possible for one of the values to already exist in our table.

Say I have an array like this:

```
const arrayOfArtistNames = ['Eminem', 'Eminem', 'Eminem', 'Biggie', 'Dr. Dre', 'Dr. Dre', 'Biggie']

arrayOfArtistNames.map(name => findOrCreateArtist(name))

const findOrCreateArtist = async (artist_name) => {
  return await ArtistIA.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      artist_name: artist_name
    },
    defaults: {
      artist_bio: ""
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
    return response[0];
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("uploads.js", 273, err);
  });
};
```

My issue is that there are multiple repeated values in my array. And when the array gets the second iteration of "Eminem", instead of finding the row sequelize literally just created, it creates another one instead.

There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to how many it duplicates and how many times.

How can I tell sequelize findOrCreate to check for values that we just created? Is there some sort of async hook or option that I am not throwing in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async await` won't work in `map/forEach...` , you have to use simple for loop :

```
const arrayOfArtistNames = ['Eminem', 'Eminem', 'Eminem', 'Biggie', 'Dr. Dre', 'Dr. Dre', 'Biggie']
const ArtistObjects = [];
for(let i = 0 ; i < arrayOfArtistNames.length ; i++) {
    ArtistObjects.push(await findOrCreateArtist(arrayOfArtistNames[i]));
}
console.log(ArtistObjects);
```

**OR**

```
const data = await Promise.all(arrayOfArtistNames.map(name => findOrCreateArtist(name)));
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Vivek!

Comment: Hey this actually is still not working in some cases. Say I'm trying to update a key_count variable, so with each iteration of a unique keyname, the database count should increment by one. Eminem, in my example, should update by +3 but only actually updates once (the queries are happening too fast and synchronously I imagine?).